# Can't register or update Solaris 11 Express

Tags: solaris, upgrade

Trying the x86 live CD, installed it on a VirtualBox virtual machine, network connectivity and guest additions are OK.

The "Register" link (which they imply is needed to get updates) gets me to an error page. The browser goes to

https://inventory.sun.com/RegistrationWeb/register/urn:st:5b620481-ea10-e3c8-f16a-99bfff4e8eac?product=OracleSolaris&version=11&locale=en_US

And then to

https://inventory.sun.com/RegistrationWeb/OracleSolaris/default/en_US/register-login.jsp

Which gives me a "Not Found" page.

The update manager says there are no updates. I imagine it'd say otherwise if I was able to register the OS. But I can't. Any clues?

(Fun fact: "Add More Software" and "Update Manager", if called, like the proverbial goggles, did nothing... until I tried to run them from the console and saw a message that "root password was expired". Aha. The "root shall never login" ideology was preventing them from running. OK, I gave root a password and was able to install much-needed software like gcc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updates for Solaris 11 Express are only available if you purchase a support contract.  There are no free updates at this time, so registering won't help there.

The [release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1479/index.html), which the download page tells you to read before installing, warn you about [the expired root password issue](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1479/fhkpy.html#gknag).

Comment: Oracle also bought Sun, so most links to sun.com fail if they don't redirect to somewhere on oracle.com